# How to run an app from api14 emulator to api10 emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I have a problem when I run an app in api10 emulator. This app can be run in api14 emulator successfully, but when i run it in api10 emulator, the application stopped at first.

Here attached the logcat info.
[image: logcat info]

[image: Lint info]

Answer (score 2):

API 10 is gingerbread which doesn't support fragments as you can see in the log cat the error is inflating the class fragment.

You would either need to use a library like `ActionBarSherlock` or the android support library may allow it, or provide an alternative layout for the gingerbread version.

**UPDATE**
If your using the support library, make sure to use `getSupportFragmentManager` not `getFragmentManager()`.

Maybe this link will also help http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-compatibility-working-with-fragments/

Comment: but i've used the support library android-support-v4.jar.

Comment: @HeikiCyan - Make sure you are importing the support fragments in your code

Comment: I'm not sure if the support library completely implements it, I tried it with my app but could never get it work on older devices

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Importet Fragments from the Supporter Library:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

If you added the minSDK in you Manifest you can run Lint to see if you are using Methods that aren't available in some of your supported Versions.
In Manifest:

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

Comment: Have you removed the import for  android.app.Fragment

Comment: sorry i'm a freshman, but what is the Lint? and how to do it.

Comment: Lint is a code analysis tool. If you set the minSD-Version in Manifest it checks if you are using Methods that aren't compatible with the minSDK-Version. You can start it via Rightclick on the project - Android Tools - Run Lint

Comment: yep i've moved the andorid.app.Fragment.

Comment: If you're still using methods that arent't compatible with older versions Lint will show it. If there is nothing, you App should work fine. Unless you forgot the minSDK in Manifest.

Comment: I updated the lint information here, but nothing wrong with that. and also I stated the minSDK. Strange.

Comment: One thing at least: If you use <fragment> Tags in ressource xml replace it with  <android.support.v4.app.Fragment>

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using new API calls. API only supports `Fragments` through the [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html), but the changes do not happen automatically just by importing the library.  You have to make sure you use the library functionality and not the newer API.  For example, you need to change your imports to use the support library.  Should look something like --

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

Add whatever other imports you need.  The other obvious difference, and probably the root of your problem is that in order to host a `Fragment`, you need to extend your activity from `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity`.

See "[Using the v4 Library APIs](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html#Using)" for more details on the support API vs the regular APIs.

Comment: i've changed as you told, but the problem still exists.